# Ajax response not being shown inside success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I display ajax response of my code? When I used `async=true` the `yy` value shown is only the last value; I need to show it for all value from `0` to `a`. It works fine with `async=false`. Here is my code:

```
for(var jj=0;jj<a;jj++){
                var yy=jj;
                var ins=12
                var rou=13
                /* */
                $.ajax({
                            type:"GET",
                             url:"Select.php",
                             async:false,
                             data:"rou="+rou+
                                 "&ins="+ins,   

                           success : function(t){

                            $("#truk"+yy).text(t);
                            // Response not shown here


                          } //success
                 });              

               }
```

Comment: A loop of sync ajax requests? That really will freeze the browser, you should think about another way maybe.

Comment: since i need all jj value , it tried with sync

Comment: I don't know exactly what your Select.php does, but isn't it easier to simply modify Select.php to return an array of strings and put the for-loop in the success function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But anyway it is the result of the ajax call what you are searching for:

```
var syncResult = $.ajax('/echo/json/', {
    async: false
});
document.write(syncResult.responseText);
```

See it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/alligator/6MsuZ/